# The use of UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uikit

> Posted immediately after the application finishes launching.

That's what the Apple docs state. But I don't see how an object could receive this notification. It would have to add itself as an observer, but the earliest it could do this is in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method. At that moment, the notification has already been posted. I don't see any use for this notification, or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume you have some object of class "MyController" in the root of your "Main Nib File" (as specified in your target's properties - the default is called "MainWindow.xib"). When your app launches and this main nib file is loaded, all objects in the nib file receive an `-awakeFromNib` method, including your MyController instance. In there, the instance could add itself as an observer of the UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification. When the loading of the Main Nib File is finished (and some other startup stuff), and the UIApplicationDelegate receives the `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` message, your MyController instance receives the notification.

Another (probably not very common) case for registering for this notification would be if you instantiated some Objective-C class directly in the main.m file before `UIApplicationMain()` is called and wanted to know when your app actually did start.

Comment: So only objects initialised by the app LOADING mechanism (the info.plist states the ".xib" or storyboard or "main class" to initialise to launch the app, and objects defined there count as appropriate) may be able to register - and receive - this notification. Other objects can register, but will never receive the notification. It is strange that Apple won't state this in their docs, and instruct developers on using this notification

Comment: Honestly, I don’t see a problem with the docs. The notification name is pretty self explanatory in that it states when it will be posted, i.e. when the application did finish launching. As a consequence, registering observers after that happens won’t have any effect. The docs also don’t state that a `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification` won’t be posted when no text is changed 

Comment: Still so very little of your code runs at time where registering this notification is still usable - that Apple should have mentioned that. Developers don't need to analyse  API behaviours and dependencies. These should clearly described, and supported by example. (I spent 2 weeks in an Apple seminar on "designing API" (with the honourable Ali Ozer) some 30 years ago - and my claims come directly from the proceedings of that seminar...

Answer (score 5):

If you have classes or categories that initialize themselves in `+load`, they can also take that opportunity to wait for an `UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification`. This way, certain objects can perform various levels of "automagic" behavior without any code needing to be inserted into the application's delegate.

Comment: I use this all the time for a whole variety of events. It lets me keep all code for initialising components in a single class. Also worth checking out is https://github.com/JaviSoto/JSDecoupledAppDelegate

Comment: Won'y help really - +load on some arbitrary class will happen only when the first instance of that code is called. So your own classes can get their +load pretty late - when first used. The meaningful time is when the app itself is loaded - meaning the .xib/storyboard/class specified in your info.plist is instantiated and created (in most cases, it will be your appDelegate).

Comment: @MottiShneor That's not true. You're thinking of the +initialize method. +load is called when the code is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to look for this notifcation?

Surely you can call whatever methods you want from the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method.

Comment: It's just something I'm wondering. Apple has to have a use for it, otherwise they wouldn't have implemented it, right?

Answer (score 0):

The delegate object that receives this notifaction is instanciated and registered as the app delegate during loading of the application .xib files. If you want to do additional setup after the .xibs have been loaded, you can do that here.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's just handy.

Instead of having your delegate, er, delegate everything, and thus forming a great dependency hairball, you can make the controllers themselves responsible for responding to lifecycle events (like becoming inactive, going into the background, etc).

Comment: I know. But this particular notification is posted when the application _finishes launching_. How can you even register an observer for this notification?