# MFP application is crashing on tapping during PUSH notification when application is not running

Tags: ios, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, phonegap-pushplugin, mobilefirst-studio

I am experiencing application crash when tapping on push notification when application is not running (even in background).
If application is running in background application crash does not occur.
Worklight version is 7.1, iOS version is 8.1.3.

For push notifications registration and receiving I am using Push plugin https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push merged with Worklight generated AppDelegate.
If needed I can send my source code.

From crash log I found that exception occurs in Push.m:
3   cmoapp                          0x10018b2a4 -[Push dispatch:] (Push.m:227)
4   cmoapp                          0x10018ad48 -[Push dispatchSelector:] (Push.m:204)

Is it possible to get from you Push.m source code to understand why app crashes?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: While the plugin you are referencing is cleverly utilizing "UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification", implementing it within the context of MF7.1 is causing conflict during the launch sequence. As "UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification" fires very early in the process (first?). you will need to refactor its handling with respect to iOS's "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" and MF's  "wlInitDidCompleteSuccessfully" methods. For more info ...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359977/the-use-of-uiapplicationdidfinishlaunchingnotification

Answer (score 0):

From a MobileFirst perspective, if you are using a *3rd party push solution instead of the one provided by MFP*, then this is not a supported scenario and support cannot be provided.

There is a built-in push support in MFP. Please use that or explain what you are not using it. See here: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/notifications/