# Using Worklight for only client side iOS push notifications (registration and receive) having 3rd-party push notifications backend

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, push

In one of our projects we try to use Worklight with Phonegap push plugin (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push). We are not using Worklight push notifications backend (and we cannot, because we have to use 3rd party push notifications backend). We only need from push notifications is to subscribe for push notifications (receive token from APNS and pass it with some user settings to 3rd party push notifications backend). We tried Worklight to use only for client side part (WL.Client.Push.registerEventSourceCallback, WL.Client.Push.Subscribe), but without any luck. The problem is, that there is no existing eventSource, which should be defined on Worklight push notifications backend (WL.Server.createEventSource). So we used Phonegap plugin for registration. And this worked (need merge Worklight and Phonegap plugin application delegates). The problem occurs when tapping on arrived push notification when application is not running (even in background). Application starts and crashes. If application is running in background application crash does not occur. Worklight version is 7.1, iOS version is 8.1.3.

From crash log I found that exception occurs in Push.m:

- 0x10018b2a4 -[Push dispatch:] (Push.m:227)
- 0x10018ad48 -[Push dispatchSelector:] (Push.m:204)

So my question is: Is it possible to use Worklight push notifications client side without Worklight push notifications backend? If yes, how? How to deal with event sources?

Primary question was asked but without detailed information: [MFP application is crashing on tapping during PUSH notification when application is not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34815638/mfp-application-is-crashing-on-tapping-during-push-notification-when-application).

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is: Is it possible to use Worklight push notifications client side without Worklight push notifications backend? If yes, how? How to deal with event sources?

Short answer: No.

Long answer: The client- and server-side APIs are tightly coupled. You cannot use one without the other.